# Angular 5 Update Parent Component value from child Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

**Child Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() OpenScheduleCall = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    onLog() {
          this.OpenScheduleCall.emit(false);
    }
}
```

**parent Component HTML :**

```
<div [(hidden)]="OpenScheduleCall">
// content
</div>
<app-schedule-call *ngIf="!!OpenScheduleCall" [prospectid]='prospectid'  [(OpenScheduleCall)]="OpenScheduleCall"></app-schedule-call>
```

I am setting the values in child component but changes are not reflecting in parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect EventEmitter import. It should be imported from '@angular/core' instead of 'events'.
The usage of [(hidden)] and *ngIf in the parent component seems redundant. Choose one approach based on your requirements.

Here's the corrected code:

**Child Component TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() OpenScheduleCall = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    onLog() {
        this.OpenScheduleCall.emit(false);
    }
}
```

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<div [hidden]="!OpenScheduleCall">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<app-schedule-call *ngIf="OpenScheduleCall" [prospectid]="prospectid" (OpenScheduleCall)="onScheduleCall($event)"></app-schedule-call>
```

**Parent Component TS:**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    // Assuming you have prospectid defined
    prospectid: any;

    // Boolean property to control visibility
    OpenScheduleCall: boolean = false;

    // Handle the event emitted by the child component
    onScheduleCall(value: boolean) {
        this.OpenScheduleCall = value;
    }
}
```

With these changes, your child component should be able to emit the event, and the parent component should be able to react to it and update the OpenScheduleCall property accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You have not marked `OpenScheduleCall` as an input to the child component, so first of all you need to do that. And to achieve two-way-binding with banana in the box, your `@Output` needs to be the `@Input` variable name, with the suffix `Change`. So first mark the variable `OpenScheduleCall` as `@Input` to child and then change the name for `@Output` variable:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() OpenScheduleCall;
  @Output() OpenScheduleCallChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  onLog() {
   this.OpenScheduleCallChange.emit(false);
  }
}
```

Now you have two-way-binding:

```
[(OpenScheduleCall)]="OpenScheduleCall"
```

Comment: Of note to anyone new to this: this only works when  the Input/Output variable names match, but the output has `Change` at the end. In this example naming the Output `OpenScheduleCallEvent` would **not** work!

Comment: @ChrisBarr I believe I have mentioned that in my answer, maybe not clearly enough (?) But thank you for your input! :)

Comment: lol, you are right - sorry!  I just used your code without reading your description, changed the var names to my liking and then remembered this trick and posted it here.

Answer (score 3):

Just `Output` cannot be in *two-way* data binding. Add also `()` at the end of the bounded function.

```
(OpenScheduleCall)="YourFunctionInParent($event)"
```

Comment: i have to set variable value `OpenScheduleCall = false`. I have to write a setter function to that.?

Comment: Output is need to get a data from the child. Your child component only has Output parameter, so you can only bind with `()`.

Comment: still, i am confused, when  `YourFunctionInParent` will trigger. can you please make the changes in my code . or suggest any working plnkr.

Comment: `YourFunctionInParent ` will trigger when the `OpenScheduleCall` in the child will emit